# Compiler unable to resolve Generic if not explicitly set

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following, simple code:

```
class Model {
    prop1: number;
}

class A<TModel> {
    constructor(p: (model: TModel) => any) {}
    bar = (): A<TModel> => {
        return this;
    }
}

function foo<T>(p: A<Model>) { }
```

Expample 1:

```
foo(new A(x => x.prop1)) // Works
```

Expample 2:

```
foo(new A<Model>(x => x.prop1).bar()) // Works
```

Expample 3:

```
foo(new A(x => x.prop1).bar()) // Doesn't work. (Property 'prop1' does not exist on type '{}'.)
```

My "problem" is now that I want example 3 work exactly like example 2. But the Ts compiler seems to be unable to "keep" the generic type, if it isn't explicitly set and the method "bar" is immediately called after the constructor.
My question now.
Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong and if so, how can I solve this?

Please let me know if some information is missing.

Comment: What type of `<TModel>` would you expect the compiler to infer from `x => x.prop1`? There are literally infinitely many types other than `Model` that could have `prop1`. (presumably, it is *not* `undefined`, but that's about it)

Comment: Just noting that `foo` does not need to be a generic function... it just confuses things; your issue persists if you make it `foo(p: A<Model>)` instead

Comment: I know Typescript can infer from return type, but what is asked here is to infer based on the member call... Don't think this is implemented.

Comment: @jcalz this is not my exact code, just an example to describe my problem. In my real code "foo" is also not called foo and has to be generic.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir but I explicitly say in foo that A has to be of Type Model and I really don't understand why "x" isn't of type Model in example 3. :/
It's working in ex. 1 but not with the bar call.

Comment: I'm saying it has no bearing on your issue whether `foo()` is generic or not, so you might as well exclude it from the example code because it can only serve to add confusion.  Your issue is that you want [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of a type's generic type parameter (`TModel` in `A<TModel>`) from the type of one of its properties (the signature of `bar()`).  TypeScript doesn't seem to do this.  Maybe it should, or it would be nice if it did, but it doesn't.  I could turn this into an answer with links I guess...

Comment: @jcalz that does seem like a complete answer to me, since there isn't a way to do this that seems as good an answer as this will get unfortunately.

Comment: FYI, this is just because `bar` is member, a function would infer based on return type as you expect it, maybe that help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Model%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%3CTModel%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(p%3A%20(model%3A%20TModel)%20%3D%3E%20any)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20bar%3CT%3E(_this%3A%20A%3CT%3E)%3A%20A%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20_this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20foo(p%3A%20A%3CModel%3E)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo(bar(new%20A(x%20%3D%3E%20x.prop1)))%20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of the [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) in TypeScript is done in a "forward in time" direction.  That is, it infers the types of an expression given the types of its pieces.  For example,

```
declare const x: string;
declare function f<T>(x: T): Array<T>;
const y = f(x); // y inferred as Array<string>;
```

In this case the type of `f(x)` is determined by the type of `x` and the signature of `f`.  This is relatively straightforward for the compiler to do, because it more or less simulates the normal operation of a JavaScript runtime, which knows `f` and `x` and computes `f(x)`.

---

But there's also [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), in which inference happens in sort of a "backwards in time" direction.  That is, the compiler knows the *expected* type of an expression and the types of *some but not all* of its pieces, and tries to infer what the type of the missing piece or pieces *must have been* to produce the expected result.  For example:

```
declare function anyX<T>(): T;
const someX = anyX(); // inferred as {}
declare function f<T>(x: T): Array<T>;
const y: Array<string> = f(anyX()); // anyX() inferred as string
```

In this case, the function `anyX()` is generic, but there is no way to infer `T` from the parameters to `anyX()` (since it takes no parameters).  And, if you just call it directly (as in `someX`), it will fail to infer and become the empty type `{}`.

But the compiler knows that `y` is supposed to be an `Array<string>`, and that `f()` will take the type of its input and return an array of that type.  So it is able to infer that `anyX()` must return a `string` in that case.

Your "Example 1" code is an instance of contextual typing which the compiler does perform: inference of function (or constructor) parameter types from its return (or instance) type.  And it works for nested function/constructor calls too:

```
const z: Array<Array<Array<string>>> = f(f(f(anyX())));
```

Now, contextual typing is great, but it doesn't happen in all conceivable situations. And apparently one place it does *not* occur is in inferring the generic type parameter of a generic type/interface/class given the types of its properties or methods:

```
type G<T> = { g: T; }
declare function anyG<T>(): G<T>;
const h: string = anyG().g; // error! no contextual typing here
```

This is the problem with your "Example 3".  The compiler does not delay inferring the return type of `anyG()` until after the type of `g` is consulted.  Instead the compiler aggressively computes the return type, and, failing to infer `T` from anything, makes it `G<{}>`.  And there's an error.

I don't know if there's a perfect answer as to *why* no contextual typing happens here.  Likely it's because it would require a lot more processing time to perform and is usually not worth it (since this use case doesn't happen all the time).  I searched [TypeScript's GitHub issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) but didn't find anything appropriate.  If you think your use case is compelling you could file an issue there (after doing a more thorough search so as not to duplicate an existing issue), but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for someone to address it.

Instead, the workaround like your "Example 2" of manually specifying the uninferred type parameter is a reasonable way forward:

```
const h: string = anyG<string>().g; // okay
```

Or, if this keeps happening to you and you'd like some more type safety, you can wrap the trouble code in a function and take advantage of contextual type inference from return type to parameter type, which we know works:

```
class Model {
  prop1!: number;
}

class A<TModel> {
  constructor(p: (model: TModel) => any) {}
  bar = (): A<TModel> => {
    return this;
  };
}

function foo(p: A<Model>) {}

// helper function to get some contextual typing
function fixIt<TModel>(p: (model: TModel) => any): A<TModel> {
  return new A(p).bar();
}

foo(fixIt(x => x.prop1)); // okay now
```

Okay, that's as close as I can get to an answer.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I really appreciate your effort to give a good answer and you truly did, I
learned a lot! Thanks! Unfortunately the fix is very hard to fit into my code, but I will find a solution. I will accept this as the answer.